# How to simplify website built with React and Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I work in a systems biology lab. Everyone, myself included, are researchers with little time or inclination for web development. But a previous lab member built a beautiful website using React and Redux. It is critical that we can maintain this website for several years and that different researchers are able to update its content on a weekly basis.

Our problem is that the website is too complicated to update. For example, to add a news story, someone has to have all the node modules installed, know how to debug JSX compilation errors, create a `Story` component and import it into the `NewsStory` view, and redeploy the node server. I can manage this now but am leaving soon; we're worried that every new maintainer will have to learn React and Redux just to update the site.

Here is my question: **Are there any React design patterns to simplify updating the content of what is basically a static site?** For example, I built another lab site using Angular, and if someone wants to update a news story, they just add a new JSON object to the `NewsController` and then upload the amended JavaScript file via an FTP server. This workflow is much easier for most people in the lab.

Comment: One can certainly write a cms in react. But that's not what your colleague did. Use the right tool for the task. Angular doesn't give you a cms out of the box either. This sounds like a job for WordPress to me.

Comment: I agree with previous comment. Also, from your description, it sounds like you're doing it wrong: the Story component should be a module that cares just about _displaying_ some content, rather than the content itself. So adding a new Story to display new content doesn't sound right. Especially since you have Redux.

Comment: Definitely doing it wrong. I'm asking whether the site can be salvaged, e.g. not ported to WordPress, by simplifying the React design patterns in some way, e.g. Angular data controller.

Comment: use [https://www.npmjs.com/package/trim-redux](trim-redux) .trim-redux is a tool for work simplify with the Redux in Reactjs. trim-redux removed reducer, combineReducer and action in redux usage process and let you work with redux like react component state!

Answer (score 2):

React is a tool for making complicated UI's easier to maintain. The flux architecture created by the Facebook team, and essentially copied, by the Redux project is a way of simplifying complex state between components as the React application grows in complexity.

It sounds like you guys swung for the fences by choosing React when it probably wasn't necessary for a simple CMS type site. There is something to be said of keeping it simple and using React for a Wordpress CMS type site is probably not keeping it simple. I recommend Django for a simple CMS solution for easy integration for authentication management especially since Python is a relatively popular option in the Biology field.

This reminds me of a funny and somewhat true tweet a co-worker of mine shared with me yesterday.  https://twitter.com/iamdevloper/status/517616294909464576

Comment: I appreciate this explanation, but I'm actually asking for solutions that do not require rebuilding the site. FWIW, I was a web developer in a previous life, and am comfortable developing this site. I am not comfortable leaving it to my coworkers in two months.

Answer (score 1):

In a way, the Redux store is your Angular data controller. You could implement the same process you're using with Angular in the Redux/React website.

So that the data (e.g. stories) are passed down to the Story component to be displayed. Have a look at this http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html.

But if you don't have enough interest/resources for learning front-end development, then you'd probably be better off with something like Word Press.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully the `Story` component could be made generic enough to render any kind of story data.

If so, here's a simple way to handle it. In the `componentDidMount()` lifecycle method of the `NewsStory` component, fetch (using axios, superagent, or fetch) all the stories from the server you wish to display (as an array of json objects) and save them in the `NewsStory` component's state. Then in the `render()` method of `NewsStory`, map over the state array to render a `Story` component for each story object (pass each story into the Story component as a prop).

The other half of this is the CRUD UI for stories. Or just manually maintain the json as you do with the Angular app.